# import from views.py does not work from app

Tags: python, django, import, django-views

I'm working with django and I'm trying to get a simple app functional.

The app is supposed to deliver a simple 'Hello world'-view but `my_app/urls.py` fails to import methods from `my_app/views.py`.

My app is named **SocialUrl**

Here is `my-project/urls.py`.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
# from SocialUrl.views import test

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^/su/', include('SocialUrl.urls')),
    # url(r'^$', test),
)
```

Here is `my-app/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^test$', views.test()),
)
```

Here is `my-app/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext

def test(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html', RequestContext(request, {}))
```

**Note:-** that the testlines in `my-project/urls.py` works correctly.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
my-project
|- my-project
|- my-app
```

I've added this in `my-project/settings.py`

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'SocialUrl', 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
)
```

I get the following error:

```
    Environment:


    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

    Django Version: 1.6.2
    Python Version: 2.7.6
    Installed Applications:
    ('django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'SocialUrl')
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


    Traceback:
    File "C:\Users\Sverker\.virtualenvs\coomba\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
      101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
    File "C:\Users\Sverker\.virtualenvs\coomba\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      318.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "C:\Users\Sverker\.virtualenvs\coomba\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
      346.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "C:\Users\Sverker\.virtualenvs\coomba\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
      341.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "C:\Users\Sverker\.virtualenvs\coomba\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
      40.         __import__(name)
    File "C:\Users\Sverker\Dropbox\Coomba\SbrgCoomba\SbrgCoomba\urls.py" in <module>
      13.     url(r'^/su/', include('SocialUrl.urls')),
    File "C:\Users\Sverker\.virtualenvs\coomba\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
      26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
    File "C:\Users\Sverker\.virtualenvs\coomba\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
      40.         __import__(name)
    File "C:\Users\Sverker\Dropbox\Coomba\SbrgCoomba\SocialUrl\urls.py" in <module>
      7.     url(r'^$', test),

    Exception Type: NameError at /
    Exception Value: name 'test' is not defined
```

I have tried various combinations of the `from . import views` line in `my-app/urls.py`
eg. `from views import test`

Edit:

still disfunctional `my-app/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from views import test

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', test),
)
```

Comment: Does `from SocialUrl import views` work for you?

Comment: No, it only works directly under my-project/urls.py, not under my-app/urls.py

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you really have this line in your app `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$', test)
```

The error says that `test` is not defined. Just define (import) it:

```
from views import test
```

Comment: the errors reffers to the test inside his app urls, not inside his porject's urls

Comment: Does not work,  i changed 'from SocialUrl.views import test' to 'from views import test'

Comment: @MihaiZamfir check the traceback.

Comment: @SverkerSbrg do you see `url(r'^$', test)` line in the app urls.py?

Comment: yeah, true alecxe, sorry. @SverkerSbrg have you saved the urls file of your project after commenting that line?

Comment: Added an updated my-app/urls.py is the new version incorrect?

Comment: @SverkerSbrg thanks, do you still see the error? If yes, is it the same as before?

Comment: @SverkerSbrg ok, do you see the `urls.pyc` file inside your app? Remove it and restart the server. Any changes?

Comment: Removed all my-app/XXX.pyc and restarted, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may cause the error:

```
url(r'^/su/', include('SocialUrl.urls')),
```

remove the leading slash and you will only have:

```
url(r'^su/', include('SocialUrl.urls')),
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: It made no difference. i still get 'name 'test' is not defined'

Comment: modify this: `url(r'^test$', views.test()),` You don't want to call the method test(), you are just pointing to it: `url(r'^test$', views.test),`

Comment: As in the updated my-app/urls.py? it did not work :/

Comment: just for safety, put a comma `,`  in your `settings.py` file after `'SocialUrl'` element in installed apps

Comment: It's already there... INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'SocialUrl',
)

Comment: I can't see it in the traceback error. can you see it?

Comment: are you sure that the file `my-project/urls.py` is saved and the line ` # url(r'^$', test),` is commented out? also, are you sure you are running the correct project and not a copy/backup of it?

Comment: removed it completely and saved, no difference :S

Comment: very frustrating....do you want to connect with me via TeamViewer and let me have a look at your code?

Comment: Havn't got it setup, would skype, screen sharing suffice?

Comment: contact me on skype. my username is mihai.zamfir90

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue - but generally I follow this pattern for my app level url files.

Main project urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('apps.main.views',
    url(r'', include('apps.main.urls')),
)
```

App level urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^test$', 'views.tests'),
)
```

Note that you should use `urlpatterns +=` or `urlpatterns =` depending on whether it is defined earlier.